# R: Occurrence times -> binary sequence?

Tags: r, binary

What are the better options to convert a non-decreasing seq of occurrence times to a 0-1 seq? Thanks.

```
d<-c(3,5,9,12,15);
c(rep(0,d[1]-1),1,unlist(rbind(mapply(rep,0,diff(d)-1),1)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should do the same

```
d <- c(3,5,9,12,15);   
x <- integer(max(d))    # initialize integer vector where all entries are zero;
                        # length(x) = max(d) (or last element of d)
x[d] <- 1L              # set x to 1 at the position of each occurence
```

Comment: good answer! may be a comment or two will help the uninitiated.

Comment: Why do you need both 1 and L? For my purpose, it's best to let L be formed by either ones or (random) sizes of events when they occur. So the answer is not good, but very good!

Comment: just for memory efficiency ;) with 1L the class of the array is integer, otherwise it is numeric; see, e.g., class(1L) and class(1)